# Processing messages fast from MSMQ in parallel from Windows Services

Tags: c#, callback, windows-services, threadpool, msmq

Our service run continuously 24/7 in a company, which retreives messages from MSMQ and after processing write result in DB. What we observe that our criteria of working with MSMQ is so old, and doesn't process many messages at a time, we need to process at least 200 or 250 transaction per second in a process, but what we uses only process 10 to 14 transaction in a second.

**implementation Of our Code is**

```
     while (true)//(count < 2)
        {
            response = "";
            try
            {
                rcvMsg = MQ.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, QTimeOut)); //Receive Messages from Message Queue
                IsReceivedTran = true;
                rcvMsg.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(types);     //Replace as one time scenerio               
                response = rcvMsg.Body.ToString();
                Msg = new Message();
                Msg.Populate(response.ToString());
                switch (Msg.TxnType)
                {
                    case Cloud.MessageLibrary.TXNTYPE.C1:
                        {
                            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(TXN1.callBack, Msg);
                            break;
                        }
                    case Cloud.MessageLibrary.TXNTYPE.C2:
                        {
                            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(TXN2.callBack, Msg);
                            break;
                        }
                    case Cloud.MessageLibrary.TXNTYPE.C3:
                        {
                            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(TXN3.callBack, Msg);
                            break;
                        }
                    case Cloud.MessageLibrary.TXNTYPE.C4:
                        {
                            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(TXNCHWREV.callBack, Msg);
                            break;
                        }
                    case Cloud.MessageLibrary.TXNTYPE.C5:
                        {
                            //Action<
                            //Task.Factory.StartNew(TXN5.callBack, Msg);
                            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(TXN5.callBack, Msg);
                            break;
                        }
                    case Cloud.MessageLibrary.TXNTYPE.C6:
                        {
                            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(TXN6.callBack, Msg);
                            break;
                        }
                    case Cloud.MessageLibrary.TXNTYPE.C7:
                        {
                            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(TXN7.callBack, Msg);
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callBack, Msg);
                            break;
                        }
                }

            }
            catch (MessageQueueException ex)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
```

As we have multiple types of Messages, we need to process all of them, every message took approx 700ms, Is there any way to process 250 to 200 messages in a second?

**Note:** We are allow to go to max version of .Net.

Comment: What work are you scheduling on the threadpool?

Comment: You are dropping exceptions silently in production code? Really? Just slowing down the process ... hmmm.

Comment: Can you identify a bottleneck? I mean did you do some tests: How many messages can your service handle if all the callbacks immediately return? Is the workload distributed on all available cores? Do you have enough memory to hold all the necessary data of concurrently executing callbacks when throughput is theoretically at 200-250? Do WorkItems pile up in the queue?

Comment: @Fildor This code is previously made by office colleagues, they have set logger in Exception. i have removed them. because My question is to use parallel threads.

Comment: Ok, but why do Exceptions need Thread.Sleep(10)? Do Exceptions occur?

Comment: @PeterBons in thread pool messages are processed and then send by socket. and then logged in to DB.

Comment: @Fildor message Queue receive logic is not good enough, because it throws exception when ever there is no message in a queue, I suggest them to make event handler to receive message. and Thread.Sleep(10) logic is not understandable by me :)

Comment: @Fildor as your previously comment about bottleneck, i can't find any relevent information about that, when ever I started googling about that, nothing could be help me, some said that thread is based on cores, if it is correct than why I am seeing more than 63 threads for any applicatoin running in 2 cores CPU? we tested application through DB log, and from our conclusion one thread pool is start after some times of other thread pool, this slow down our process and at a time 10 to 14 thread pool are running in our CPU.

Comment: 2 Cores seems not enough for this. See on 2 Cores, you can have much more (OS) Threads than 2 but only 2 can run *really* concurrently. So increasing the Thread count can become counter-productive because of context-switch overhead. Using the Threadpool improves that drawback. Using the TPL would even be better.

Comment: If your co-workers cannot give a very good explanation for that Thread.Sleep(10), I'd try to get rid of it.

Comment: @Fildor I know that this (Thread.Sleep) not make any sense, but unfortunately whenever I tried to change that particular code, I have restricted, but finally this time I have a choice to change all draw backs. Can you give any example of TPL on particular scenerio, because I have tried but none of them will work, more over how many core machine the currently code will work? will you give me idea?

Comment: I deliberately did not give an example of TPL because I guess that would imply some heavier refactoring. I'd solve one problem at a time. 1. Get rid of sleeps. 2. Try if you can power-up the machine (cores & RAM) 3. Use more recent version of .net (may improve optimization) ... I cannot possibly give an estimate on how many cores would be sufficient/optimal because I don't know the overall environment. And finally the connection to the DB could also be a bottleneck. Start by monitoring the load of your machine. Is CPU percentage constantly high? If so, more cores help.

Comment: Check CPU usage while a lot of concurrent messages are being processed. If it's stuck at 100%, your thread pool is saturated with work and throwing more threads at the problem won't help - in this event you need better hardware. If average CPU usage is significantly below 100%, then you're most likely dealing with IO work scheduled in a blocking fashion and switching over to TPL or another genuinely async technology will help - at least if the bottleneck is within your application (and not due to external factors).

Comment: I suspected the DB (or your "processing") because you said you run into receive-timeout for "no messages". If the MSMQ was saturated you would never have receive timeouts because there would always be a message ready to receive.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for guiding, and give your precious time, I tried my best for finding solutions from your giving advice.