# Task.StartNew.ReceiveAsync() not working properly while receiving messages from MSMQ

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, msmq

I am using **Implementation** Phase of this URL [how-can-i-read-messages-from-a-queue-in-parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34590433/6002727), it is working well when i used before,  after some time it is not working, i doesn't understand what is happening? After spending time I conclude that program stop at particular method.

```
/// <summary>
    /// APM -> TAP conversion for MessageQueue.Begin/EndPeek.
    /// </summary>
    private static Task<Message> PeekAsync(MessageQueue messageQueue)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(messageQueue.BeginPeek(), messageQueue.EndPeek);
    }
```

when I comment out this implementation on `RunAsync()` method , and calling `ReceiveAsync()` Method

```
 /// <summary>
    /// APM -> TAP conversion for MessageQueue.Begin/EndReceive.
    /// </summary>
    private static Task<Message> ReceiveAsync(MessageQueue messageQueue, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(messageQueue.BeginReceive(timeout), messageQueue.EndPeek);
    }
```

then program terminate, there is no exception, neither any thing happen. Simply program is terminated.

from mine perspective `Task.Factory.FromAsync()` is a reason, but not undesrtand why??

if I am using same queue with receiving messages as `BeginReceive()` eventhandler it is working OK. How to identify about this??

Comment: You can subscribe to UnhandledException for current `AppDomain`

Answer (score 0):

In the `ReceiveAsync` function, the second parameter of `FromAsync` should be `messageQueue.EndReceive` instead of `messageQueue.EndPeek`.

Comment: u are right, I have implement same thing also, but not working

Answer (score 0):

First things first.

As @xwlantian pointed out. Your mixing up your APM method pairs.

You should always match your `BeginXXX` with the correct `EndXXX` method. Otherwise you get an exception.

In your case

```
Task.Factory.FromAsync(messageQueue.BeginReceive(timeout), messageQueue.EndPeek)
```

Should read

```
Task.Factory.FromAsync(messageQueue.BeginReceive(timeout), messageQueue.EndReceive)
```

However, you should have been able to fix this yourself, if you had the correct information (the exception/stacktrace). Which you claim was missing.

This is not true.

The reason you didn't see an exception is that Visual Studio did not `break` on your exception (which is the typical way you "find" exceptions). Instead, you can go look at your Windows Event Viewer, and you should find the exception there.

## Why did you not "see" the exception?

The following were true

1. Your exception occurred on a background thread with no try/catch pair up the stack.
2. You did not have a exception handler on the AppDomain.
3. You have "Just My Code" checked in your "Debugging" settings.

Comment: I have tested it with same pairs also, but not work. i am checked through your given information later

Comment: But how to test `Task.Factory.FromAsync<Message>(messageQueue.BeginReceive(timeout), messageQueue.EndReceive);` as it is new task and it's implementation is hidden, more over it is quit when debugger run this line. please explain

Comment: Did you take a look at the exception where I told you to look? My psychic powers can only take me so far. Give me your exception/stack trace if you want more help.

Comment: There is no exception occured at that point, program terminate on that line, and stack trace screen disaapear after termination of program.