# C# Multithreading and pooling

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

Hello fellow developers,

I have a question about implementing multi-threading on my .NET (Framework 4.0) Windows Service.

Basically, what the service should be doing is the following:

- Scans the filesystem (a specific directory) to see if there are files to process
- If there are files that need to be processed, it should be using a thread pooling mechanism to issue threads up to a predetermined amount.
- Each thread will perform an upload operation of a single file
- As soon as one thread completes, the filesystem is scanned again to see if there are other files to process (I want to avoid having two threads perform the operation on the same file)

I am struggling to find a way that will allow me to do just that last step.

Right now, I have a function that retrieves the number of maximum number of concurrent threads that runs in the main thread:

```
int maximumNumberOfConcurrentThreads = getMaxThreads(databaseConnection);
```

Then, still in the main thread, I have a function that scans the directory and returns a list with the files to process

```
List<FileToUploadInfo> filesToUpload = getFilesToUploadFromFS(directory);
```

After this, I call the following function:

```
generateThreads(maximumNumberOfConcurrentThreads, filesToUpload);
```

Each thread should be calling the below function (returns void):

```
uploadFile(fileToUpload, databaseConnection, currentThread);
```

Right now, the way the program is structured, if maximum number of threads is set, say, to 5, I am grabbing 5 elements from the list and uploading them.
As soon as all 5 are done, I grab 5 more and do the same until I don't have any left, as per code below.

```
for (int index = 0; index < filesToUpload.Count; index = index + maximumNumberOfConcurrentThreads) {
                try {
                    Parallel.For(0, maximumNumberOfConcurrentThreads, iteration => { if (index + iteration < filesToUpload .Count) { uploadFile(filesToUpload [index + iteration], databaseConnection, iteration); } });
                } 
                catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException outOfRange) {
                    debug("Exception in Parallel.For [" + outOfRange.Message + "]"); 
                }
```

However, if 4 files are small and the upload of each one takes 5 seconds, while the remaining one is big and takes 30 minutes, I will have, after the 4 files have been uploaded, only one file uploading, and I need to wait for it to finish before starting to upload others in the list.

After finishing uploading all the files in the list, my service goes to sleep, and then, when it wakes up again, it scans the file system again.

What is the strategy that best fits my needs? Is it advisable to go this route or will it create concurrency nightmares? I need to avoid uploading any file twice.

Comment: First of all, if you don't actually use functionality of  `System.Thread`s then you may want to switch to `System.Task`s. Secondly, if the scenario of having 4 little files and 1 large file is common then this strategy imho is not advisable (and here goes one more reason to use `Task`s; while you're using threads all of the "workers" that are done most probably are blocked until  the slowest in the group finishes, so you have like 5 threads that take resources but only one is working).

Comment: Thirdly, you may want to re-create your design to have (for example, just a variant) N+1 worker loops, where N are going through the chain "take file from list => process it => take the next file..." and one is updating the list by searching for the differences on the disk. Yes, you would need to implement some simple synchronization around you singleton list but it's not too hard nor it can become a performance hit (you mentioned that there is some database to connect to, so compared to network communication time even millions of synchronization operations would probably mean nothing).

Comment: Oh, my bad, I see that you're using TPL's `Parallel.For` so you're already using `Task`s. Well then, the second part of my comment holds - try some worker loops, maybe it can get faster.

Comment: Also please note, that `Parallel.For` does not guarantee that it would launch everything in parallel (which is actually good but anyway, I though I should mention it). To better conficure it one can pass additional options as parameters to it and set [`MaximumDegreeOfParallelism`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (I do not recommend doing it though).

Comment: Here is a link that appears on the same process of what you're trying to accomplish, I hope this helps.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437298/how-can-i-read-messages-from-a-queue-in-parallel)

Comment: @DD84 Looks like the link you provided might just be the one I was looking for. Will try it out and update the original post after.